# Stop PHP for loop after 5 valid results

Tags: php, arrays, for-loop

I have a PHP for loop that brings in an array of 11. Currently, the loop prints out all 11. But in middle of this for loop I have an if statement that checks another value, so in the end, its possible that the loop prints out less than 11.

```
$countarray = count($the_big_array);
for($i=1; $i <= $countarray; $i++) {
$earow = $the_big_array[$i];

......
$something = 200; //this number than vary

   if ($something < 3600){

echo $earow[0];
echo $earow[3];

    }
}
```

My question is: How do I make sure that the loop looks through the full set of Array, yet prints out *only 5* Valid results?

Comment: How do you define what is a valid result?

Comment: Count valid results, if its 5, use 'break;'

Comment: Why do you need to look through the full array if you only need to print 5? Let's say the first five meet your criteria, then why loop through the rest also?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to maintain a counter of valid values, and use that to break from your loop. For example:

```
$num_valid = 0;
for($i=1; $i <= $countarray; $i++) {
    // do stuff
    if (/* value is valid */) {
        $num_valid++;
        if ($num_valid == 5) break;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm using a foreach loop instead as it seems you are using the loop in a "foreach" manner.
Here I just check if the counter is past five and not echo, but I let the loop keep going.

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($the_big_array as $earow){
    ......
    $something = 200; //this number than vary

    if ($something < 3600 && $counter < 5){
        echo $earow[0];
        echo $earow[3];
        counter++;
    }
}
```

Another option if you need to enter this something if on every iteration is to put another just by the echo.

```
$counter = 0;
foreach($the_big_array as $earow){
    ......
    $something = 200; //this number than vary

    if($something < 3600){
        if($counter < 5){
            echo $earow[0];
            echo $earow[3];
            counter++;
        }
        // Now you can do stuff here
        // on every item without echo
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like:

```
$counter = 0;
$countarray = count ( $the_big_array);
for ( $i = 1; $i <= $countarray; $i++)
{
  $earow = $the_big_array[$i];

  ......
  $something = 200; //this number than vary

  if ( $something < 3600)
  {
    echo $earow[0];
    echo $earow[3];
    counter++;
  }
  if ( $counter == 5)
  {
    break;
  }
}
```